# Multiplication Tables c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a multiplication table chart that looks like the following:

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
   ----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|  10|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 2|   2|   4|   6|   8|  10|  12|  14|  16|  18|  20|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 3|   3|   6|   9|  12|  15|  18|  21|  24|  27|  30|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 4|   4|   8|  12|  16|  20|  24|  28|  32|  36|  40|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 5|   5|  10|  15|  20|  25|  30|  35|  40|  45|  50|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 6|   6|  12|  18|  24|  30|  36|  42|  48|  54|  60|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 7|   7|  14|  21|  28|  35|  42|  49|  56|  63|  70|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 8|   8|  16|  24|  32|  40|  48|  56|  64|  72|  80|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 9|   9|  18|  27|  36|  45|  54|  63|  72|  81|  90|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
10|  10|  20|  30|  40|  50|  60|  70|  80|  90| 100|
 -|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
```

I'm having trouble getting the lines that are inside of the table. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to put those dashed lines inside of my nested for loops or if I have to create a separate loop for them.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= tableNumber; i++)
{
    cout << setw(5) << i;
}

    cout << endl << "   ";

for (int x = 1; x <= tableNumber; x++)
{
     cout << "----|";
}

     cout << endl;

for (int row = 1; row <= tableNumber; row++)
{
    cout << setw(2) << row << "|";

  for (int col = 1; col <= tableNumber; col++)
  {
    cout << setw(4) << row*col;
    cout << "|";
  }

  cout << endl << endl;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

I'd recommend looking at the end of your for-loop that has the nest inside of it. At the end, you just print two endlines. Perhaps instead of printing two endlines (which creates a gap in between each row), you can get it to print something else. ;-)

(I'm assuming this is homework mind you, so I'm trying not to give it away--no fun in that!)

Comment: @user3424158 Experiment a little with the printed strings and see what happens.  I am sure you will find a solution and learn a couple things in the process.  Stepping through with the debugger will help see what to do quicker.

Comment: I was able to match the lines for a table with 10 rows and 10 columns but the only problem is that the user may enter any number between 1 and 10. So in this case, wouldn't I have to implement some sort of for loop to add the correct number of series of dashed lines?

Comment: @user3424158 take a look at the second for-loop you wrote in your original question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much James! I got my table to look exactly how i wanted, but i felt like I sorta cheated with that last ' cout << "-|" ' haha. this is what i added after the nested for loop. cout << endl << " ";

 for (int x = 1; x <= tableNumber; x++)
 {
   cout << "-|---";
 }

  cout << "-|";
  cout << endl;

Comment: @user3424158 glad you got it. :-) A little cheating never hurt anyone. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should set a row of the table, then go through and add the bottom lines. Increase the row value and continue.

Example:

```
int r (1);
while (r < rowNumbers)
{
    for (int c = 1; c < colNumbers; c++)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << row*col;
        cout << "|";
    }

     cout << endl

    for (int x = 1; x <= colNumbers; x++)
    {
         cout << "----|";
    }

    court << endl;
    r++;
}
```

This puts the lines under the numbers, then moves to the next row.

Comment: before starting of second for loop, you should write cout << endl;

Comment: I think cout<<endl; should come before second loop but you are adding after second loop, why?

Comment: I think cout<<endl; should come both side i.e after and before second for loop. in first for loop it should print numbers and then it should come to the next line and then print (----|) below that number and after printing it, again go to next line(for second set as you said). :P :)

Comment: @Himanshu Yes haha my ignorance paid... If I had debugged this I would have noticed immediately haha